# How to cast a Long value into a LongFilter?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I am trying to cast a Long value (id) into the LongFilter of the class TagCriteria that uses private LongFilter postId; to create an object that I can use to query

```
public ResponseEntity<List<TagDTO>> getAllTags(TagCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable)
```

BUT I do not see how to do it as the Java Doc is not really clear to me.

```
public class TagCriteria implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LongFilter id;
    private StringFilter tagName;
    private LongFilter postId;

    public TagCriteria() {
    }
}
```

Filter class for Comparable types, where less than / greater than / etc relations could be interpreted. It can be added to a criteria class as a member, to support the following query parameters:

```
  fieldName.equals = 42
  fieldName.specified = true
  fieldName.specified = false
  fieldName.in = 43,42
  fieldName.greaterThan = 41
  fieldName.lessThan = 44
  fieldName.greaterOrEqualThan = 42
  fieldName.lessOrEqualThan = 44
```

Due to problems with the type conversions, the descendant classes should be used, where the generic type parameter is materialized.

Type parameters:

```
<FIELD_TYPE> the type of filter.

See also:
IntegerFilter
DoubleFilter
FloatFilter
LongFilter
LocalDateFilter
InstantFilter
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Long longValue = 1L;
LongFilter longFilter = new LongFilter();
longFilter.setEquals(longValue);
```

If you need to call a REST Service, you can specify the value using queryParam.

For example, if you have a resource 'Person' with an attribute 'name', and you need to retrieve all people with name 'John':

```
api/person?name.equals=John
```